# Reverse Engineer Auto-Generated C?

Tags: python, c, reverse-engineering, cython

How easy is it to reverse engineer an auto-generated C code? I am working on a Python project and as part of my work, am using Cython to compile the code for speedup purposes.

This does help in terms of speed, yet, I am concerned that where I work, some people would try to "peek" into the code and figure out what it does.

Cython code is basically an auto-generated C. Is it very hard to reverse engineer it?

Are there any recommendations that would make the code safer and reverse-engineering harder to do? (I assume that with enough effort, everything can be reversed engineered).

Comment: How about compiling the C code and only distributing the compiled version?

Comment: "I am concerned that where I work, some people would try to 'peek' into the code and figure out what it does." You work with somebody, but they can't see your source code? Something sounds *very* wrong about this...

Comment: Sven: yes, the only version that is 'distributed' is the compiled version. I am just concerned and wonder how hard it is to figure out what the code does.

Jerry: in some companies, some groups compete with each other and each one wants to keep its proprietary information to itself.

Comment: @user54009: perhaps you should write an obfuscator -- might make good fodder for your resume, which you apparently need to update; finding a new/different job should apparently be your top priority.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The right question is: *How motivated would your "opponents" be to reverse-engineer your code?*

Comment: @Jerry: +1 Espionage within the same company... I don't know what to say...

Comment: thkala: very motivated. is there anything I can do about it? any protection schemes to make the code better? should I switch to c++?

Comment: @thkala: I know what to say: "Run, Forrest, run!"

Comment: @user540009: The competition within your company is so bad that you are actually considering switching your code to a different programming language? I'd switch to *a different job* instead!

Comment: @user540009: I agree with Jerry and thkala. Why exactly are you trying to *hide* code from your *co-workers*? This doesn't make any sense from a business perspective. Does the company promote this behavior?

Comment: @Adam: yes; they want the groups to compete and see who makes more money. so obviously, some things are kept secret.

Comment: @user540009: "so obviously, some things are kept secret".  Not obvious.  Indeed, it sounds a lot like you're making most of this up.

Comment: 1. Have you tried looking at compiled Cython code and trying to reverse engineer it? 2. Is this is a financial/investment company that you work for?

Comment: @user540009: Wow... That sounds incredibly *strange*. Is your company in the business of making software or is software development just another department? I'm genuinely curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay -- to attempt to answer your question more directly: most auto-generated C code is *fairly* ugly, so somebody would need to be fairly motivated to reverse engineer it. At the same time, I don't believe I've never looked at what Cython generates, so I'm not sure how it looks.

In addition, a lot of auto-generated code is done in the form of things like state machine tables, that most programmers find fairly difficult to follow even at best. The tendency (in many cases) is to have a generic framework, with tables of data that the framework more or less "interprets" at run-time. This isn't necessarily impossible to follow, but it's enough different from most typical code that most people will give up on it fairly quickly (and if they do much, they'll typically waste a lot of time looking at the framework instead of the data, which is what really matters in cases like this).

I'll repeat, however, that I'm pretty sure I haven't looked at what Cython produces, so I can't say much about it with any real certainty.

There are (or at least used to be) commercial obfuscators intended to make C source code difficult to understand. I suspect the availability of Perl has taken a lot of the market share from them, but if you look you may still be able to find one and use it.

Absent that, it's not terribly difficult to write an obfuscator of your own, but the degree of effectiveness will probably vary with the amount of effort you're willing to put into it. Just systematically renaming any meaningful variable names into things like `_` and `__` can do quite a bit (e.g., `profit = sales - costs;` is a lot more meaningful than `_ = _I_ - _i_;`). Depending on the machine generated code in question, however, this may not really accomplish much -- obfuscating a generic framework may not make much difference in understanding what your code does -- and if they figure out the procedure you're following, they may be able to simply replicate the correct framework code and transplant the pieces specific to your program into the un-obfuscated framework.

Comment: Thank you Jerry for this detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should really take a look at the code that Cython produces. To help with debugging, for example, it copies the complete Python source code into the generated file, marking each source line before generating C code for it. That makes it very easy to find the code section that you are interested in.

A very nice feature is that you can compile your code with the "-a" (annotate) option, and it will spit out an HTML file next to the C file that contains the annotated Python code. When you click on a line, you'll see the C code for that line. As a bonus, it marks lines that do a lot of Python processing in dark yellow, so that you get a simple indicator where to look for potential optimisations.

There's also special gdb support in Cython now, so you can do Cython source level debugging etc.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I guess I missed the bit that you were talking about the *compiled* module, whereas I was only referring to the source code that Cython generates. I agree with Jerry that it will be fairly tricky to extract something useful from the compiled module, as long as you keep the gdb support disabled (the default) and strip the debugging symbols. That is because the C compiler will do lots of inlining of helper functions all over the place and apply various low-level code optimisations, thus making it harder to extract the original macro level code patterns. However, you will see named C-API calls to CPython, and you will also see function names from your own code. Cython isn't specifically designed for code obfuscation, quite the opposite. But readable assembly has certainly never been a design goal.